# random in numpy is not generating random number

Tags: python, numpy, random

Guys I am using to generate a random system, and because of it's function, I want to choose the random module in Numpy. but when I wanted to implement it, I realize that Numpy will not really generate a psedu-random number. briefly, the result of following code is 0 every time:

```
    import numpy as np
    for i in range(10000):
         n[i] = np.random.randint(0,1)
```

as I mentioned, all of the cell's in n have the zero value. even when I add a pause between each iteration i still have the same result.

```
    import time  
    import numpy as np
    for i in range(10000):
         n[i] = np.random.randint(0,1)
         time.sleep(2)
```

that is not the case when i use the build in random module. 
Since this problem could really affect the integrity of my result, I would highly appreciate any command regarding how can I overcome this issue or why is this happening.

PS: that is not the case when i import Numpy in IDLE and simply just print

```
  np.random.randint(0,1)
```

again and again. in this situation the result is look like random.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `high` argument of `numpy.random.randint(low, high)` is an exclusive range, like `range(low, high)`. You want `numpy.random.randint(0, 2)` to have an equal chance of generating a 0 or a 1.

This differs from the standard library's `random.randint()`, which uses an inclusive range. The inclusive range is broadly considered to be a design mistake. The naming of the two functions is mostly coincidental; `numpy.random.randint()` descends from `Numeric`'s `RandomArray` module that predates the standard `random` module, and was designed for backwards compatibility with `RandomArray` to ease the transition from `Numeric` to `numpy`.

Answer (score 1):

[`randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) generates numbers between `a` and `b-1`, so if you want random binary numbers use either of the following:

```
np.random.randint(0,2)
np.random.randint(2)
```

Also, you can generate the array at the same time using:

```
n = np.random.randint(2, size=10000)
```

Not sure why IDLE is producing different behaviour than the documentation I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

"randint" generates only whole numbers in the range specified, in your code only the number 1 can be used.
Instead of using:

```
randint(0,1)
```

Use something with a higher value after the comma, such as:

```
randint(0,2)
```

To create a random number that is either 1 or 2.

Also, If you use the built-in random function you can generate random float values between 0.0 and 1.0:

```
import random
randnum = random.random()
print(randnum)
```

This gives an output reminiscent of a value such as "0.1798164301328583", and you can use simple python math to make them into the required values.